# Trouble with computer finding DVD or USB drive to boot from on windows xp system

Tags: boot, windows-xp

I am trying to install Ubuntu while uninstalling windows xp.  I have downloaded the 14.04.2 Ubuntu file to the desktop of another computer and burned it to a DVD.  next I changed the computer bios to boot from the CD/DVD drive.  when I restart the computer it says it can't boot from the drive.  I also tried the same thing using a USB drive with the same result... what might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just burn the .iso file to the media.  You have to prepare it to make it bootable.  Directions are [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) for USB and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) for DVD.

Comment: Thanks so much, I thought I was missing something concerning the burning of the disk.  I will try this tomorrow morning and see if I can get it to work!

Comment: I just got it uploaded and everything seems to be going well!  Do you know if I need to have antivirus software for Ubuntu?

Comment: That's a topic you should read up on by searching the site. Meanwhile if this answer helped you, please mark it as correct by clicking the gray checkmark by the answer